# Blank page - phalconphp

Tags: php, frameworks

Can you tell me, why when i trying add new action to ex. AboutController in clear invo example, get blank page after if I enter to site/about/blabla? In PhalconPHP framework.

Answer (score 1):

See http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html
If you are using default routes from phalcon with `yoursite.tld/controllerName/actionName/params` then you should have create the controller with said name and the action inside it.

So for your example, if you said you are using the invo example, the url `site/about/blabla` is valid only if your controller class is called `siteController`, inside you have the public method `aboutAction` wich take on parameter that will have the value 'blablabla'.

But if you have you app in an subfolder of you document root, called site, the all the explanation before this shifts one position to the left.. `aboutController` and `blablaAction`.

You also might want to add your controller/action pair int the ACL in `app/plugins/SecurityPlugin.php`

Comment: I mean "site" like ex. localhost, mysite.com

Comment: Your question is far from clear. But the second explanation covers that part also.